# "Temps plein" vs. "Temps complet"

Tags: choix-de-mot, travail

I was walking yesterday in Paris and saw that two different shops were looking for new employees. One was advertising for a "serveur à temps plein" position, the other one for a "serveur à temps complet" position. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le contexte d'un contrat de travail, *à temps plein* (ou *à plein temps*) et *à temps complet* sont synonymes, et signifient que la durée journalière / hebdomadaire effective est égale à la durée légale. On trouve « [temps complet](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alegifrance.gouv.fr+%22temps+complet%22) » et « [temps plein](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alegifrance.gouv.fr+%22temps+plein%22) » à peu près aussi souvent dans les textes de lois.

Et je dirais que *à temps complet* et *à plein temps*, au contraire de *à temps plein*, s'utilisent parfois aussi dans le registre familier pour désigner une activité qui occupe tout le temps disponible, souvent de manière péjorative.